# Creating a lag variable in a Python Sframe by group

Tags: python, lag, sframe

Hi I am trying to identify the lag variable for a set of groups in a python Sframe.

The code I am using is:

```
sf['lag'] = sf.groupby(['Group'])['Num'].shift(1)
```

However I am getting the error:

> TypeError: groupby() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Comment: If you use the editing tools you can ensure that the code examples are formatted correctly. You can also format the errors as a separate message. Also, you don't need to end with "Thanks in advance" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate which aggregation functions you would like the`groupby` operator to do. For example

```
import sframe
import sframe.aggregate as agg

grp = sf.groupby(key_columns='Group', 
                 operations={'count': agg.COUNT('Group')})
```

Check out the documentation at https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.groupby.html#graphlab.SFrame.groupby